# Stress testing with pycassa

Tags: benchmarking, cassandra, pycassa

I've been trying to write a stress tester for a rather large cassandra database. At first I was doing it from scratch, and then I found [stress.py](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/tools/py_stress) which allows you to stress test your cluster. However, like all benchmarks, the test data is unrepresentative of the loads this database will be seeing. Thus I decided to modify it to be more realistic to my usage pattern.

I'm using pycassa for most of this project. However stress.py uses the lower-level thrift interface directly, which I find rather cumbersome. Are there any projects out there which stress test cassandra using pycassa? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing general-purpose stress tests that make use of pycassa; I'd also love to hear about them if there are any.

In the past, I've modified stress.py to make use of pycassa.  I believe I set it up to use one small ConnectionPool per process and I was pretty happy with the result; modifying the Operation class and get_client was the main chunk of work here.

It's hard to give more specific details about this without knowing what you want to do, so feel free to ask more detailed questions if you need to.